# About Hamming and Manhattan priorities computation for 8 puzzle

Tags: algorithm, computation, hamming-distance

http://coursera.cs.princeton.edu/algs4/assignments/8puzzle.html

Is this Hamming and Manhattan priorities computation from the above link correct?

> For example, the Hamming and Manhattan priorities of the initial search node below are 5 and 10, respectively.
>
> Note that we do not count the blank square when computing the Hamming or Manhattan priorities.

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Why do you doubt it? Do you have another answer?

Comment: But Sedgewick or Wayne wrote "Note that we do not count the blank square when computing the Hamming or Manhattan priorities.".

Comment: I think 4 and 8 are correct.

Comment: Ah, now i see what confuses you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, 3 of them are in the places and 5 not in the right places. This gives as 5 as Hamming distance, and some small manipulations needed to see that Manhattan priority is 10.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Yola for detailed explanation. I understand.